# Start multiple processes in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My goal is to start multiple processes inside a batch file based on number of cpu cores on a given machine. I came up with the script below which seems to be working fine but not sure if this is the most optimal way of doing it.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set arg1=%1

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`wmic cpu get NumberOfCores`) DO (
  SET str=%%F
 )
set str=%str:NumberOfCores =%
FOR /L %%n IN (1,1, %str% ) DO ( start %arg1% )
```

Comment: The OS sets the variable `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` automagically by default.

Comment: @Magoo Number of cores are not necessarily same as number of processors. For example on my laptop  I have 1 processor but 2 cores.

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding, the environment variable `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` represents the logical number of processor which isn't the number of cpu sockets but the number of cores eventually doubled with HT/SMT.

See the ouput of this wmic command

```
> wmic cpu get NumberOfCores,NumberOfEnabledCore,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value

NumberOfCores=4
NumberOfEnabledCore=4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=8
```

Using start as often as  `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` doesn't guarantee the started program is distributed on the logical processors. Read `start /?` => Node,Affinity

```
@Echo off
For /f %%A in ('wmic cpu get NumberOfCores /value^|find "="') Do Set /A %%A
Set Num
```

Sample output:

```
NumberOfCores=4
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
```

Comment: Is there a way that value of no of cores can directly be assigned to a script variable? At the moment I'm using "set str=%str:NumberOfCores =%" which seems bit of a hack.

Comment: See channged  answer.

Comment: When executing the script above with find command on nanoserver getting error 'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: find.exe should be in `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe` an alternative is findstr.exe

Comment: I do need number of cores and not the logical processors (as I mention in my original post). After replacing find with findstr the script above gives "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2" but what I need is "NumberOfCores=1" (which is the case on the test machine as its 1 cpu core and 2 logical processor)