# Set a value in batch file variable from a CMD command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to get value of this command `wmic cpu get numberofcores` from CMD (I just need the number) and set it to a batch file variable `totalcore` . Anyone can help me with that? I tried some codes and googled but got no answer for this question.

Comment: It's a plague, I tell you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140215/sharing-folder-via-batch-script-on-french-windows/46141020#46141020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set totalcore=Unknown
for /F %%A in ('wmic cpu get numberofcores') do @if %%A GTR 0 set totalcore=%%A

echo NumberOfCores=%totalcore%
```

Answer (score 1):

Well with a [different title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030310/start-multiple-processes-in-batch-file) this was answered 9 days ago.

```
@Echo off
for /f %%A in ('wmic cpu get numberofcores^|findstr "^[0-9]"') do set /A totalcore=%%A
```